# Sending more than one character from Qt to Arduino

Tags: c++, qt, arduino, communication

First of all: Sorry I'm not very good with english.

I'm making a serial communication between Qt (C++) and an Arduino. First I tried to send one character ('1') to the Arduino to turn the LED on and it worked. Now I want to send more than one character. How can I send more characters so each character will be a variable in the Arduino code?

This is my Qt code for one character:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    serial.setPortName("com17");
    serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    serial.write("'0'");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using the QSerialPort class from QT.

As you can see from the documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport-members.html), you have three functions overloading the write(...), from the super class

```
write(const char *, qint64) : qint64
write(const char *) : qint64
write(const QByteArray &) : qint64
```

What you are actually sending with `"'0'"` is actually a string composed by three characters, two single quotes and the number zero.

If you'd like to send more than one character, you have to pack all the characters into a QByteArray.

You'll have to call serial.write() in the following way

```
QByteArray ba;
ba.append('1')
ba.append('2')
ba.append('3')
etc...
serial.write(ba)
```

In this way you send data composed by three bytes { '1', '2', '3' }

Answer (score 0):

Without the knowledge of your code for the Arduino I can't help in detail. What you basically have to do is the following:

- Send some characters to the serial interface with your Qt application. You can do this with additional calls to `serial.write()`.
- On the Arduino side, you have to implement a loop (or better catch an event) that checks if serial data is available.
- In that loop (or the caught event) you can then read each character and assign it to a variable.

Have a look at the [documentation for `Serial.read()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/read) and [`serialEvent()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SerialEvent).

Answer (score 0):

The best option to send data is using a protocol which you can define yourself.

It's best to worth with hex.

First define a packet start byte and packet stop byte. For example 0x00 and 0x01.

Have the arduino loop read from serial in. Until it finds 0x00. Once it finds this start byte. Read every character into an array until 0x01 is found which is the stop byte.

Also in case 0x01 is displayed in the data use a escape byte.